# possible to set remote IP Address (with IPCP) via Windows Dial Up?

Tags: ip, dialup

is it somehow possible to set the IP Address of the remote device, using IPCP, when using a Windows Server for a Dial Up Connection via ISDN?

e.g. via Linux it is simple calling pppd with option local_IP_address:remote_IP_address

But how can this be done with a windows server, I can only find the option to set the local IP Address in the IPv4 settings of the Dial Up Entry.

Thanks!